# How can I force a very long script in mysql client to exit quickly on error without it hanging for hours

Tags: mysql

I have a very long SQL script with roughly 250,000 updates.

I run it by piping it to the mysql client in linux. Three times now I hit errors in the SQL caused by the way the script was generated.

```
cat updates.sql | mysql -h kkwea1sprageyxq.poopopakte0b2.pu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com \
    -u mama_ --disable-reconnect --max-allowed-packet=536M \
    --default-character-set=cp1250 --skip-column-names -D mydb > update.log
```

The mysql client seems to hang when there is an error, often for hours, before erroring out itself.

I could set it to ignore the errors, but I would like to know whether I can add a flag to the command line in mysql client to cause it to error quicker after an SQL error.

I can see several potentially interesting command-line flags for mysql, but I find the description for them ambiguous.

My script runs in auto-commit mode OFF, with `COMMIT` statements every 25 update commands. I have hunch that it errored much quicker when I was using auto-commit mode ON, which is obviously desirable, if there's an error.

Here's an example of the update statement in case it helps:

```
UPDATE data SET value = 0.9234 WHERE fId = 47616 AND modDate = '2018-09-24'  AND valueDate = '2007-09-01'  AND last_updated < '2018-10-01';
```